# boto3 copy vs copy_object regarding file permission ACL in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

After I copied an object to the same bucket with a different key and prefix(It is similar to renaming, I believe), its public-read permission is removed.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'otherbucket', 'otherkey')
```

When I tried to open the file on a browser using the link found on s3. And, I realized that on the permission tab, it doesn't have public-read permission while the original file has.

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>***</RequestId>
    <HostId>***</HostId>
</Error>
```

2 questions:
i) Is is possible to maintain the ACL permission when I use 
[copy](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy)(CopySource, Bucket, Key, ExtraArgs=None, Callback=None, SourceClient=None, Config=None)

ii) What are the ExtraArgs that I can set? The document doesn't mention anything.

Comment: Side-note: If possible, avoid putting permissions directly on objects. If you wish to make objects public, it is better to create a **bucket policy**, which can make a whole bucket, or part of a bucket, public (regardless of the ACL set on the specific objects). This is easier to maintain and administer rather than having different permissions on each object. (But, sometimes there is a good reason for having per-object permissions, too.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not the exact answer that I want but it seems to work for now.

I am not sure how to maintain the permission but I can manually set it to public-read or other types that I need it to be.

This are the possible values from boto3 [copy_object](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object):
'private'|'public-read'|'public-read-write'|'authenticated-read'|'aws-exec-read'|'bucket-owner-read'|'bucket-owner-full-control'

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}
extra_args = {
    'ACL': 'public-read'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'otherbucket', 'otherkey', extra_args)
```

Then, I realized it needs more permission to perform this action. I am not sure which permission it actually needs now but I get these errors:
i) An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied.
ii) An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied.

It works after I added "s3:PutObjectAcl" policy.

Comment: Try to use `MetadataDirective: 'COPY'`